# How to put your CiviCRM Contacts on a Leafleft Map in 5min?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, cms-integration, geocoding, map

To summarize: someone asked me to post this here - so that he can give it a try!

- put a PIN based on latitude/longitude of the CiviCRM Contact
- put CiviCRM Contact data in the bubble pop-up
- color the PIN based on value of a CiviCRM Custom field

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Leaftlet is an open-source JavaScript Library for interactive mobile friendly maps. It only takes a few minutes to put your CiviCRM Contacts on a Leaflet Map if you're using Drupal.

Here are some of my slides from my CiviCON 2016 lightning talk:

**EDIT: Some additional notes based on comments below and some questions emailed to me:**

- To get started with CiviCRM - Drupal integration make sure you have
  CMS integration set up Administer: civicrm/admin/setting/uf?reset=1
- add a filter to not bother w/ non-geocoded addresses:  Filter
  Criteria: CiviCRM Address: Latitude (not empty)

**EDIT: for this example I used: drush pm-list** --type=Module --no core --status=enabled
(and relevant...)

CiviCRM CiviCRM (civicrm) 4.6.18
Other IP Geolocation Views & Maps (ip_geoloc) 7.x-1.28
Other Leaflet (leaflet) 7.x-1.3
Other Leaflet Markercluster (leaflet_markercluster) 7.x-1.2
Other Libraries (libraries) 7.x-2.2
Views Views (views) 7.x-3.14

Don't forget Leaflet module requires you to install leaflet library in /libraries (either your sites/all/libraries or your specific site's /libraries).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

UPDATE: now requires this patch for ip_geolocate module -> https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/ip_geoloc_plugin_style.inc_.patch

Comment: nice suggestion - have used Views and OpenLayers in past. thought I should try this out ;-) ..... not clear if leaflet_views was required (which required geofield). currently just getting white page instead of map. tested on same site with Leaflet map based on content and had no issues. will come back to this some other time

Comment: hey Pete - leaflet_views is not required (is disabled; I just double checked) - did you hook up the CiviCRM Lat and Lon fields in Settings -> Map (Leaflet API) (5th slide from the top)?

Comment: yep - i did that. only went back to leaflet-views when i got nowhere, so good to know it wasn't required. it obviously was when i wanted to do a drupal content only version of the map to check it wasn't something else like ht auth blocking me etc

Comment: and i had a 'page' view using same civi tables to ensure i did have data that 'should' be showing ;-)

Comment: I'm also getting a blank page...

Comment: Ok my turn to reproduce this!

Comment: Ok I just completely went from scratch - on a site that had never even used GeoCoding and/or any other mapping - and all looks good - will add in a few more bits (possible gaps) in my Answer & will list all module versions!

Comment: Pete & Yossi: do you have a filter to handle non geocoded addresses? I just set it up on a site that didn't even have any Views integration in the settings.php yet. If this doesn't help then I'll post an entire pm-list. PS - are you on 4.6.x?

Comment: Strange... you can see my setup here: https://www.evernote.com/l/ANwKWTTPqqhKupaze4Hr1gPhdt3RzU5ypyM

Comment: I don't have Contextual links nor Dropdown links. In the one I created this morning I just have CiviCRM Contacts: Contact ID, CiviCRM Address: Latitude and CiviCRM: Longitude and 1 Filter: CiviCRM Address: Latitude (not empty) - will post the pm-list - w/ module versions

Comment: PS - what do you have for CiviCRM Location Display Options? If got out-of-the-box: AND Any

Comment: Any errors/notices in the browser console? And/or the PHP log?

Answer (score 2):

Just to note that this stopped working around CIVICRM 4.7.19.

You need to apply the patch to Drupal IP_geoloc module here:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2861393

Comment: I just put my CiviCamp Calgary participants on a Leaflet map and I did not need this patch

Comment: I did the set up as per the answer above, and was hitting the same blank white screen that others reported in the previous comments. I went to https://www.drupal.org/node/2861393 and looked at reviews of the patch, and folks reporting success with it - being able to see maps using the Leaflet API. So, I installed it, and can now see mapped addresses using the Google API alternative, though still do not using the Leaflet API alternative. When I tried mapping a large number of addresses using the Google API alternative, I got the same white/blank screen, so scaled that down to 250 with success.

Comment: I used Karin's recipe and it worked with Google but not Leaflet. I then checked the correct leaflet js was added. The module checks for http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.0.2/leaflet.zip - when I installed the js from this everything worked.