# Leaflet map + Drupal Views + 400 CiviCRM contacts data = performance?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, geocoding, performance, jquery

We try to pull CiviCRM  contacts data incl. multiply custom fields and display on map. There are around 400 contacts to display, yet map page loads a bit slower, than expected (5 to 10 seconds). It has been worse initially even at quite powerful server, but we've got significant improvements using combination of:

- Redis
- nginx ngx_http_gzip_module
- fine-tuned MySQL (via mysqltuner.pl)
- Drupal caching and  Views Accelerator module

Any advice on how to make it loads as fast as possible (up to, say 2-3 seconds) please?

Drupal 7x and CiviCRM 4.6x

**UPD** Views query

> SELECT civicrm_address.geo_code_1 AS civicrm_address_geo_code_1, 
>   civicrm_address.geo_code_2 AS civicrm_address_geo_code_2, 
>   civicrm_contact.organization_name AS
>   civicrm_contact_organization_name,  civicrm_website.url AS
>   civicrm_website_url, 
>   civicrm_value_society_chairman_10.public_contact_for_society_988 AS 
>   civicrm_value_society_chairman_10_public_contact_for_society, 
>   civicrm_address.street_address AS civicrm_address_street_address, 
>   civicrm_contact_civicrm_relationship.id AS 
>   civicrm_contact_civicrm_relationship_id,
>   civicrm_value_society_chairman_10.subs_rate_single__38 AS
>   civicrm_value_society_chairman_10_subs_rate_single__38,
>   civicrm_value_society_chairman_10.meeting_day_time_1_531 AS
>   civicrm_value_society_chairman_10_meeting_day_time_1_531,
>   civicrm_value_society_chairman_10.meeting_day_time_2_532 AS
>   civicrm_value_society_chairman_10_meeting_day_time_2_532,
>   civicrm_contact.id AS id FROM  {civicrm_contact} civicrm_contact INNER
>   JOIN {civicrm_relationship} civicrm_relationship_civicrm_contact ON
>   civicrm_contact.id = civicrm_relationship_civicrm_contact.contact_id_a
>   AND (civicrm_relationship_civicrm_contact.relationship_type_id = '59'
>   AND civicrm_relationship_civicrm_contact.is_active = '1') LEFT JOIN
>   {civicrm_relationship} civicrm_relationship ON civicrm_contact.id =
>   civicrm_relationship.contact_id_a INNER JOIN {civicrm_contact}
>   civicrm_contact_civicrm_relationship ON
>   civicrm_relationship.contact_id_b =
>   civicrm_contact_civicrm_relationship.id LEFT JOIN {civicrm_address}
>   civicrm_address ON civicrm_contact.id = civicrm_address.contact_id
>   LEFT JOIN {civicrm_website} civicrm_website ON civicrm_contact.id =
>   civicrm_website.contact_id LEFT JOIN
>   {civicrm_value_society_chairman_10} civicrm_value_society_chairman_10
>   ON civicrm_contact.id = civicrm_value_society_chairman_10.entity_id
>   WHERE (( (civicrm_address.geo_code_1 IS NOT NULL ) AND
>   (civicrm_address.geo_code_2 IS NOT NULL ) AND
>   (civicrm_contact.contact_type IN  ('Organization')) AND
>   (civicrm_contact.contact_sub_type IN  ('Society')) )) LIMIT 1000
>   OFFSET 0

Comment: Yeah that should not take this long. Can you post your views query?

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT Thank you for reply! Have added it to post body.

Comment: Can you confirm whether the issue is the above sql? e.g. on the views admin page, you can get it to tell you how long the query takes. Views caching would be one obvious route. If that's not an option, then maybe verify whether you really need all those fields to display your map - I notice that most of the expensive part (e.g. the relationship and custom fields) are not required for the selection criteria, so if you're not actually displaying them, it would seem a waste.

Comment: @AlanDixon Unfortunately, we need all fields included to View. According to  Views internal performance info (w/o Devel), it looks like this: 

** Query build time 2.57 ms
Query execute time 3.05 ms
View render time 3.15 m **

Comment: Ok ms sounds good - are you using the modules/set up described here: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12862/how-to-put-your-civicrm-contacts-on-a-leafleft-map-in-5min -

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT Yes, except Markercluster, and starting to think may be clustering  results will help..

Comment: How do you shown relationship on the map? Colouring the Markers perhaps?

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT Even worse I'm afraid.. We retrieve related contact data via CiviCRM API calls inside Views TPL files and show it in map popup..Sometimes we retrieve data of related contact of related contact..

Comment: Aha! So there is a lot more going on - I'd suggest put some debug/statements into your custom code to figure out how much time is spent where

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT Absolutely! Thank you btw., sometimes just talking to someone helps..there is a special expression for it, don't remember it. Anyway, have just realised there is much more going on under the hood.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like those tpl files are the issue, not views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We think the answer is that the performance issues are (very likely) in the custom code/tpls - that get invoked as well. We've determined that the Views query itself was not the issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535020/tracking-the-script-execution-time-in-php

Comment: Have to check if issue caused by custom code / tpl; will accept the answer if so. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how the time delays are not in your custom code/tpl - as it's not the views query - and it's not leaflet 