# Use map with election boundaries on

Tags: map

I use maps to see where my volunteers are. It would be cool to see them on a map with the electoral boundaries on top. Is it possible to change the “base layer” map from google or wherever to a google map that I had put the ward boundaries on.....?

Answer (score 1):

It is not really possible within CiviCRM. However if you are on Drupal you could create a view and put that view on a map with your own layer.

Comment: I am using drupal so presumably since Civicrm contact location fields are available to drupal views then I will be able to create a page which is a drupal with map and location markers?

Comment: I know that it is possible but I do not know how to do it. You probably have to start looking into how to make a drupal view with/on a map.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should find the instructions at [How to Map Contacts?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24670/how-to-map-contacts/24726#24726) helpful particularly the link to another Answer by Karin to this great answer [How to put your CiviCRM Contacts on a Leafleft Map in 5min?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12862/how-to-put-your-civicrm-contacts-on-a-leafleft-map-in-5min) which we have used and concur it gives us Maps with civi contacts